# Efficient expanding OLS in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I would like to explore the solutions of performing expanding OLS in pandas (or other libraries that accept DataFrame/Series friendly) efficiently.

1. Assumming the dataset is large, I am NOT interested in any solutions with a for-loop;
2. I am looking for solutions about expanding rather than rolling. Rolling functions always require a fixed window while expanding uses a variable window (starting from beginning);
3. Please do not suggest `pandas.stats.ols.MovingOLS` because it is deprecated;
4. Please do not suggest other deprecated methods such as `expanding_mean`.

For example, there is a DataFrame `df` with two columns `X` and `y`. To make it simpler, let's just calculate beta.
Currently, I am thinking about something like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

def my_OLS_func(df, y_name, X_name):
  y = df[y_name]
  X = df[X_name]
  X = sm.add_constant(X)
  b = np.linalg.pinv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
  return b

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2.5,3], 'y':[4,5,6.3]})

df['beta'] = df.expanding().apply(my_OLS_func, args = ('y', 'X'))
```

Expected values of `df['beta']` are `0` (or `NaN`), `0.66666667`, and `1.038462`.

However, this method does not seem to work because the method seems very inflexible. I am not sure how one could pass the two Series as arguments.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `RecursiveLS` (recursive least squares) model from Statsmodels:

```
# Simulate some data
rs = np.random.RandomState(seed=12345)

nobs = 100000
beta = [10., -0.2]
sigma2 = 2.5

exog = sm.add_constant(rs.uniform(size=nobs))
eps = rs.normal(scale=sigma2**0.5, size=nobs)
endog = np.dot(exog, beta) + eps

# Construct and fit the recursive least squares model
mod = sm.RecursiveLS(endog, exog)
res = mod.fit()
# This is a 2 x 100,000 numpy array with the regression coefficients
# that would be estimated when using data from the beginning of the
# sample to each point. You should usually ignore the first k=2
# datapoints since they are controlled by a diffuse prior.
res.recursive_coefficients.filtered
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have explored this solution. Even though it works for standalone arrays, it is unclear how it may be applied to an expanding DataFrame (e.g. df.expanding()). The desired results are one beta for each row, as the expanding progresses.

Comment: You would have to do that in a loop or by using the `apply` method, there is nothing built-in that I know of for that.

Comment: A for-loop is not in the scope (see my first point in the question). For an expanding object (from ```df.expanding()```), it is unclear to me how to use ```apply``` on it with arguments.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your comment well. No, I doubt that you could easily use this in combination with the df.expanding(). But you don't need to; `res.recursive_coefficients.filtered` contains what you're looking for.

Comment: Would you please edit your answer with the information from your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is now [part of statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.html)